# Specific Face Rich Polyhedra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-optimization, polyhedra

So I'm familiar with different polytopes where the number of facets is greater than the number of vertices and vice versa.

Examples include:

The n-dimensional cube, which in general as $2n$ codimension 1 faces and $2^n$ codimension n faces.

Then of course the dual of the cube which has $2n$ codimension n faces and $2n$ comdinesion 1 faces.

Now I'm curious however if there exists a class of shapes, where the codimension-k face $k \ne 1, n$ is minimal over all possible faces. In some sense if we assign a natural number to the total count of the faces of a particular codimension. Then need this list have it's smallest values at the ends? Or is it possible for the list to have its largest values near the middle?

Comment: In three dimensions, you cannot have more edges than vertices/facets due to Euler's polyhedron formula. This argument, of course, does not apply to higher dimensions.